# Linq get new list from a list of object property which is a list itself

Tags: c#, linq

So I have a list like this:

```
{
  "images": [
    {
      "imageLink": "link1",
       "pIds": [
        "id1"
      ]
    },
    {
      "imageLink": "link2",
      "pIds": [
        "id2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "imageLink": "link3",
      "pIds": [
        "id2"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to create a list which contains all the unique pIds from above list . How Do I do so?
I am trying it like this

```
var pIds  = oldList.Select(p=>p.Ids).ToList();
```

but I dont want List of lists just the elements inside the pIds in oldList.

like:

```
pIds = ["id1","id2"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0) to *flatten* the nested enumerations:

```
var pIds  = oldList
  .SelectMany(p => p.Ids)
  .Distinct() // to get unique ids
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Perfect , I didn't realize SelectMany flattens the enumerations.Thanks.